# Grails Searchable Plugin Cannot Find Imported MySQL Data

Tags: grails

I converted a web application to Grails and I am using the Searchable plugin to search for data. I've had no problems with this until I imported existing legacy data from the old MySQL database to the new one used by my Grails application. The search will not find any imported data in the database, but it will find any data added from within the Grails application.

I'm assuming that I have to index the imported data somehow, but I'm not sure where to start looking.  Can anyone lend a helping hand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is in the docs ;)

You can do one of two things:

1. Index at startup: for that, you need to configure the plugin.

   1. First, install the configuration: `grails install-searchable-config`
   2. Then, make sure that the bulk index is set to true. There should be a line like this in the config file conf/Searchable.groovy: `bulkIndexOnStartup = true`
2. Reindex manually. You can do that on any Controller: `searchableService.reindex()`

Comment: Thanks, GalmWing! That's exactly what I was looking for. I already had  the configuration installed with bulkIndexOnStartup = true. So I restarted my application on tomcat, and the imported data is now indexed and the search works perfectly. Thanks again!